# BLTouch does not compensate for bed level correctly

Tags: marlin, bltouch, anycubic-i3-mega

- Printer: Anycubic Mega S.
- Mods: BLTouch, Dual material with G-code-powered switch.
- Firmware: Marlin 2.0

A couple of weeks ago I had a print failure when printing PETG. Now whenever I use auto bed leveling, it doesn't compensate correctly. The nozzles will be too high on the left side of the bed, and too low toward the right. I checked my firmware configuration, and everything appears to be OK. I also suspect that the failed print may have knocked the Z endstops out of alignment.

I recalibrated the Z-offset on the BLTouch and ran a probe repeatability test. Everything came out fine. My `Configuration.h` can be found [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ccp6dzft8mo2h1j/AAD7-gjMG4wRQvafq-cwiFPUa?dl=0). As well as a picture of the hotend setup below.

Edit: I tried leveling the bed manually before using ABL. Still had the same problem.

Edit 2: I looked more closely at the bed leveling logs and noticed that it is reading the bed level incorrectly, contrary to my previous tests.
I do not know what this means, but I suspect it has to do with misaligned endstops. Could this be correct?

[image: My dual nozzle/material mod for the Anycubic I3 Mega/Mega S]

Comment: Are your nozzles perfectly level? What you're describing sounds like they aren't.

Comment: @Rykara, you are correct, the nozzles were misaligned. I releveled them, but the original problem still lingers.

Comment: You think one Z axis might be slightly higher than the other? Have you aligned them to the same height like in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6QhUgq4C008)?

Comment: Alright, I tried re-aligning the Z axis a couple times. It didn’t solve the problem. However, the distance from the bed to the nozzle at each side changed slightly (w/ auto leveling active).